# Navigator: creating an HTML with JS for browser version/name/height/width

Tags: javascript, navigator

My code that I am using to return the current version of the browser in use for my html document is returning NaN. I have completed my code, and felt pretty good about it, but the navigator.useragent is not returning the proper output.

```
/// javascript
function getBrowserName() {
    var lsBrowser = navigator.userAgent;

    if (lsBrowser.indexOf("MSIE") >= 0) {
        return "MSIE";
    } else if (lsBrowser.indexOf("Firefox") >= 0) {
        return "Firefox";
    } else if (lsBrowser.indexOf("Chrome") >= 0) {
        return "Chrome";
    } else if (lsBrowser.indexOf("Safari") >= 0) {
        return "Safari";
    } else if (lsBrowser.indexOf("Opera") >= 0) {
        return "Opera";
    } else {
        return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}

function getBrowserVersion() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var browser = getBrowserName();
    var findIndex = ua.indexOf(browser) + browser.length + 1;
    var browserVersion = parseFloat(ua.substring(findIndex, findIndex +3));

    return browserVersion;
}
var browserName = getBrowserName();
var browserVersion = getBrowserVersion();
var windowHeight = window.screen.availHeight;
var windowWidth = window.screen.availWidth;

 document.write("You are using " + browserVersion + " version of the "
 + browserName + " browser to view this page in a browser whose inner" + 
 " window that is" + windowWidth + " pixels wide and " +
 windowHeight + " pixels tall.");

/// html doc
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lan= "en">
<head>
    <title> Chapter 8 Browser Sniffing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src = "browserSniffing.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am expecting my code to fill in these blanks:
You are using version  _________  of the  ____________  browser to view this page in a browser whose inner window that is _____ pixels wide and _____ pixels tall.
It is filling them all. But the getBrowserVersion function is returning NaN. Maybe somebody would be so kind as to give some advice on how to slightly tweak this code to work properly.

Comment: I believe this `var browser = getBrowserName;` should be replaced by `var browser = getBrowserName();` inside `getBrowserVersion()` function.

Comment: Huh... see an extra eye always helps. I thought I had it pretty squared away, but that slight mistake was the issue. Thank you @Shidersz

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
/// javascript
function getBrowserName() {
    var lsBrowser = navigator.userAgent;
debugger
    if (lsBrowser.indexOf("MSIE") >= 0) {
        return "MSIE";
    } else if (lsBrowser.indexOf("Firefox") >= 0) {
        return "Firefox";
    } else if (lsBrowser.indexOf("Chrome") >= 0) {
        return "Chrome";
    } else if (lsBrowser.indexOf("Safari") >= 0) {
        return "Safari";
    } else if (lsBrowser.indexOf("Opera") >= 0) {
        return "Opera";
    } else {
        return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}

function getBrowserVersion() {
  debugger
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var browser = getBrowserName();
    var findIndex = ua.indexOf(browser) + browser.length + 1;
    var browserVersion = parseFloat(ua.substring(findIndex, findIndex +3));

    return browserVersion;
}
var browserName = getBrowserName();
var browserVersion = getBrowserVersion();
var windowHeight = window.screen.availHeight;
var windowWidth = window.screen.availWidth;

 document.write("You are using " + browserVersion + " version of the "
 + browserName + " browser to view this page in a browser whose inner" + 
 " window that is" + windowWidth + " pixels wide and " +
 windowHeight + " pixels tall.");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lan= "en">
<head>
    <title> Chapter 8 Browser Sniffing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src = "browserSniffing.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```